# @PathVariable List<UUID> in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, propertyeditor, path-variables

In a Spring MVC controller a `@PathVariable Long... ids` get resolved fine when passed input like `1,2,3`.

If the parameter is declared as `@PathVariable UUID... ids` then the comma-separation doesn't work: a 400 response is returned.

Can I implement a custom `PropertyEditor` to handle `UUID[]` or `List<UUID>`? The only examples I can find are for single values, not collections/arrays.

**UPDATE**

As per [Phil Webb's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867729/774395), after reporting the issue as a bug on the Spring JIRA, the kind folks at SpringSource added support for this in Spring 3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue will be fixed in Spring 3.2. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9765 for details.

Comment: Excellent! I saw the JIRA updates, so thanks. Is there an ETA for 3.2?

Answer (score 2):

You can register a custom converter this way:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
class UUIDConverter implements Converter<String, UUID> {

    @Override
    public UUID convert(String source) {
        return UUID.fromString(source);
    }

}
```

and register it with Spring MVC:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="....UUIDConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>


<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"> 
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Now if you submit UUID's it should get correctly mapped to a list.

Comment: Spring MVC is already correctly mapping single UUIDs though, and this doesn't mention `List` anywhere?

Comment: What I meant is that if you submit a list of UUID's this way: uuid1, uuid2,uuid3 then it will get correctly mapped to a `List<UUID>` parameter. Is this not what you are expecting, I may have misunderstood your question then.

Comment: Here is a gist which shows the scenario - https://gist.github.com/3638121 , here I am binding to a `UUID...` (uuid varargs field)

Comment: Thanks a lot Biju. What I don't understand is that without the customer `Converter` implementation, Spring MVC could bind a single `UUID` just fine - so there must exist a UUID converter in the Spring MVC framework somewhere. The part I don't get is that just by adding your custom `Converter`, which makes no mention of lists, the framework is prompted to use split apart the input string in the first place. This could be considered a bug in Spring MVC?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I debugged it a little more, there is a `org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.UUIDEditor` which converts correctly when a single UUID is passed, but fails for an array. It does sound like a bug.

Comment: I've raised a bug on the Spring JIRA: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9765

Answer (score 0):

For annotation based configuration you just need to add `@Component` annotation to the class

```
package com.demo.config.converters;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.UUID;

@Component
public class StringToUUIDConvertor
  implements Converter<String, UUID> {

    @Override
    public UUID convert(String source) {
        try {
            return UUID.fromString(source);
        }
        // just changing default message to the one I like to see.
        catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input UUID string");
        }
    }
}
```